# JavaFX TitledPane fixed size

Tags: java, javafx

I have an window with two `TitledPane` into an `VBox`.

`TitledPane` resize his width based on window size, but I want `TitledPane` to have a fixed size.

Main class:

```
public static void main(String[] ar){ launch(ar); }

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage){

    ControlPane controlPane = new ControlPane(); //extends TitledPane -> content = HBox -> Button + Pane + Button
    TitledPane logView = new LogViewPane(); //extends TitledPane -> content = HBox -> TextField + Button + Button

    VBox vbox = new VBox();
    vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10));

    VBox.setMargin(controlPane, new Insets(0, 0, 10, 0));

    vbox.getChildren().addAll(controlPane, logView);

    var classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();

    Scene scene = new Scene(vbox);
    scene.getStylesheets().addAll(classLoader.getResource("control-status-style.css").toExternalForm(),
                                    classLoader.getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.sizeToScene();

    primaryStage.show();

}
```

ControlPane class:

```
public class ControlPane extends TitledPane{

    private final Button start, close;
    private final Pane status;

    public ControlPane(){

        super("CONTROL", null);

        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        hbox.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        start = new Button("START");
        close = new Button("CLOSE");

        status = new Pane();
        status.setMinWidth(10);
        status.setMaxWidth(10);

        HBox.setMargin(start, new Insets(0, 10, 0, 0));
        HBox.setMargin(status, new Insets(0, 10, 0, 0));
        HBox.setMargin(close, new Insets(0));

        hbox.getChildren().addAll(start, status, close);

        this.setCollapsible(false);
        this.setContent(hbox);

    }

}
```

LogViewPane class:

```
public class LogViewPane extends TitledPane{

    public LogViewPane(){

        super("LOG", null);

        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        hbox.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        TextField inputDate = new TextField();
        inputDate.setMinWidth(100);
        inputDate.setMaxWidth(100);

        Button buttonLog = new Button("LOG");
        Button buttonChart = new Button("CHART");

        HBox.setMargin(inputDate, new Insets(0, 10, 0, 0));
        HBox.setMargin(buttonLog, new Insets(0, 10, 0, 0));
        HBox.setMargin(buttonChart, new Insets(0));

        hbox.getChildren().addAll(inputDate, buttonLog, buttonChart);

        this.setCollapsible(false);
        this.setContent(hbox);

    }

}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

I want it to looks like this:

[image]

How I can prevent to expand/contract TitledPane, without using set(Min/Max)Size?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use set(Min/Max)? That's what they are created for. You could also use set(preferredSize).

Comment: Try calling [setFillWidth(false)](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/VBox.html#setFillWidth%28boolean%29) on your VBox.